# Git Error: Remote repository could not read from

Tags: github, git-push

```
riya@RFL113:~/Documents/EventsAcross_ReactJS$ git push origin master
ERROR: Permission to RiyaKapuria/EventsAcross_ReactJS.git denied to railsfactory-riya.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exist
```

I'm getting this error while pushing in master. I'm having two git account in same system with two SSH Key.

I'm following https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Add railsfactory-riya as collaborator with Write permissions on GitHub.

Comment: How to add as collaborator?? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Go to your repo -> Settings -> Collaborators and Teams -> At below you should be able to add

Comment: Now the push is happening by railsfactory-riya profile. But I want to use RiyaKapuria.